# Plugin Controller not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am using Cakephp 2.5 and trying to create a plugin called BankTaxes, for now it shows the error message controller not found.

I do follow the  [Create plugin tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html)  and i can see the contact index view as expected.

At my Plugin i see Controller not found error message:

```
Error: BankTaxesController could not be found.
Error: Create the class BankTaxesController below in file: app\Controller\BankTaxesController.php.
```

How can i fix it?

I have the following structure :

```
//App/Config/Bootstrap.php : 
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

My Controller:

```
// In /app/Plugin/BankTaxes/Controller/BankTaxesAppController.php
class BankTaxesAppController extends AppController {

}
```

My Model

```
// In /app/Plugin/BankTaxes/Model/BankTaxes.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class BankTaxesAppModel extends AppModel {

}
```

Comment: What url you are hitting ?

Comment: `class BankTaxesAppModel extends AppModel {` This class name is wrong, and it extends the wrong class - use Bake to create files and avoid errors like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL to Your controller in Plugin should be look like this: `http://localhost/app_name/:plugin_name/:controller_name`

For example:
`http://localhost/app_name/bank_taxes/bank_taxes`

Comment: I could reach the plugin via url. Now there is another issue a missing table from a model where i do map to another table using $usetable property. The model is PaymentPerson and it maps to persons table. The error message is : missing PaymentPerson table